# is build b144 the current latest version for java-7?

Tags: java, java-me, java-7

its already past [2nd June](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/)! Btw I just want to know is it true that the features stated at [Pure Danger](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/) are accurate?

If not does anyone know where can be get an accurate overview of the finalized features in Java 7?

And just one quick question, in the [Download Page](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/), it lists the version for the download at 26-may? Does anyone know where can we download the 2nd June version (latest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can find on the [JDK7 early access download](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html) page is the latest current build. If that's b144 at the moment, then yes, b144 is the latest current build.

The list at Pure Danger looks accurate. The official source is ofcourse the OpenJDK website, which you have a link to in your own question, so if you want to know what the changes and new features are from the horse's mouth, [look there](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/).

Why are you so anxious for the June 2 version? If it's not there then wait a few days longer, or follow the [mailing lists](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo) if you want to follow exactly what's happening. According to the [milestone schedule](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/milestones/), the June 2 release is going to be b145.

Comment: of course i'll want the latest version asap. i don't like the feeling when i'm working on one version.. then suddenly something changed (and i'm oblivious to what's the change..) so i rather just start fresh

Comment: If you're so anxious to follow the releases, then subscribe to the mailinglist, where you can most likely also get info on why the June 2 release seems to be delayed.

Comment: Build 145 has now been released: http://jdk7.java.net/download.html changes: http://download.java.net/jdk7/changes/jdk7-b145.html

Comment: dang, I'd thought i had myself subscribed already but i received no notifications!

Comment: If you use Twitter you can also follow @OpenJDK (that's where I saw it first).